# powershell - How to wait for user input

Tags: powershell

I am trying to prevent users from shutting down the computer in certain situations. I am displaying a confirm message to do that. This is how my script looks like:

```
$sysevent = [microsoft.win32.systemevents]

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $sysevent -EventName "SessionEnding" -Action $OnShutdown -SourceIdentifier "ExecuteOnShutdown"

$OnShutdown = 
{

    Write-Host  -ForeGround Green $event.SourceEventArgs.Reason

    $OUTPUT= [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Do you really want to shutdown the computer?." , "confirm" , 4)

    Write-Host  $OUTPUT

}
```

This works fine but i dont know how do i suspend the shutdown command till user clicks "yes" or "no". Is there a way to prevent the system shutdown and wait for the user to click "yes" or "no" and then shutdown the server based on the answer?

Answer (score 0):

In your event handler scriptblock there are a number of automatic variables defined one of which is `$EventArgs`.  In this case there will be a `Cancel` property on this object you can set to $true but the docs warn:

> When set to true, this property requests that the session continue to
>   run. It provides no guarantee that the session will not end.

There is also another variable defined in this context - `$Sender`. Execute `man about_automatic_variables` for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Consider deploying your script via group policy or a local policy shutdown / logoff script which should prevent shutdown until your condition is met.  You might need to wrap your messagebox call in conditional sleep loop (which is what I did for something similar in VBScript years ago!), maybe not.

If you choose to use this method, you may also want to include a preferred default selection for your messagebox (perhaps after a specified timeout period has elapsed?); a user may not hang around to see your mesaagebox as it will be drawn after the interactive desktop has unloaded.

Here's a link to a Technet article about how to  [Use Startup, Shutdown, Logon, and Logoff Scripts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753404.aspx).

I'm not sure if this answers your question as this won't prevent the shutdown, it just stops it until your condition is met.